# Flutter how to display map with 3rd-party vector tiles (.pbf)?

Tags: flutter, maps, gis, vector-tiles

I have 2 vector tile sources, the format is like this:
[http://35.137.120.5:8080/geoserver/gwc/service/tms/1.0.0/country:layer1@EPSG:900913@pbf/{z}/{x}/{y}.pbf](http://35.137.120.5:8080/geoserver/gwc/service/tms/1.0.0/country:layer1@EPSG:900913@pbf/%7Bz%7D/%7Bx%7D/%7By%7D.pbf)
[http://35.138.119.4:8080/geoserver/gwc/service/tms/1.0.0/country:layer2@EPSG:900913@pbf/{z}/{x}/{y}.pbf](http://35.138.119.4:8080/geoserver/gwc/service/tms/1.0.0/country:layer2@EPSG:900913@pbf/%7Bz%7D/%7Bx%7D/%7By%7D.pbf)

I need to display them on top of each other (2 layers).

However, I cannot find any example from any library that shows how to display vector tiles from 3rd party sources like this. I have looked at `flutter_map`, and `mapbox_gl`, but still couldn't find any example for this feature.

Can someone make a small, complete `main.dart` that solve this problem? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

In web apps with leaflet, you have one style that use several sources (vector tiles, bitmap tiles…)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).